# Fill Jtable with local JSON file

Tags: java, json, swing

am trying to get all the data from a json file and fill the data to a jtable, I already get the data from the json file and printout but i cant put the data on the jtable when i try to fill the data on the jtable inside the loop i ended up multiplying the frame insted the data.  please help me on this my code are bellow:

I already imported all jar needed.

```
public Main(){
    super(new GridLayout(1,0));
    BufferedReader br = null;
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    String inputline;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/Users/lyod/Documents/sample.json"));
        try {
            String id = null,
            component = null,
            title = null,
            lat = null,
            lng = null,
            cost = null,
            status = null;
            Object[][] data;
            while ((inputline = br.readLine()) != null) {
                JSONArray a = (JSONArray) parser.parse(inputline);
                String[] columns = new String[] {
                    "Id", 
                    "Title",
                    "Component",
                    "LAT",
                    "LNG",
                    "Cost"
                };
                for (Object o : a) {
                    JSONObject sample = (JSONObject) o;
                    id = (String) sample.get("id");
                    component = (String) sample.get("component");
                    title = (String) sample.get("title");
                    lat = (String) sample.get("lat");
                    lng = (String) sample.get("lng");
                    cost = (String) sample.get("cost");
                    status = (String) sample.get("status");
                    Object[][] data = new Object[][] {
                        {id,title,component,lat,lng,cost, false },
                    };
                }
                JTable table = new JTable(data, columns);
                add(new JScrollPane(table));
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("test v2");
                frame.add(table);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Main();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `when i try to fill the data on the jtable inside the loop i ended up multiplying the frame insted the data` - exactly. Why would you create a new table and frame for every iteration of the loop??? You should only create one table and one frame AFTER the loop is finished executing. So the basic logic is to create an empty DefaultTableModel before the loop starts. Then inside the loop you use the `addRow(...)` method of the DefaultTableModel to add data to the model. Then after the loop finishes you use the TableModel to create the table and add the table to the frame.

Comment: can i access the data inside the loop then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example the populates data from a regular text file. It demonstrates the concepts of reading data from a file within a loop and then create the table after the loop is finished.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableFromFile extends JPanel
{
    public TableFromFile()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        JTable table = new JTable( getTableModel() );
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        add( scrollPane );
    }

    private TableModel getTableModel()
    {
        String delimiter = ":";
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();

        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = getFileReader();

            //  First line will contain the column names

            String line = reader.readLine();
            model.setColumnIdentifiers( line.split(delimiter) );

            //  Remaining lines in the file will be the data

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                model.addRow( line.split(delimiter) );
            }

            reader.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }


        return model;
    }

    private BufferedReader getFileReader()
    {
        //  Create data to simulate reading data from a file

        String data =
            "Letter:Number\n" +
            "A:1\n" +
            "B:2\n" +
            "C:3";

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new StringReader( data ) );

        //  In your real application the data would come from a file

        //Reader reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(...) );

        return reader;
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table From File");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new TableFromFile() );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I don't know what the format of a JSON file is like but the "concept" should be the same.

So replace the logic that read a single line of data and parses the data with the logic that parses a line of JSON data.