# How to import JCheckBox from text file data into JTable

Tags: java, swing, boolean, jtable, jcheckbox

I am working on a project that imports and exports JTable data to a text file using Java NetBeans. I want to display a column of JCheckBoxes under the header Status. Furthermore, when importing the data, I want the individual JCheckBoxes to be selected if the text file says true or deselected if the text file says false.

My text file looks like this:

```
Index#Task#Type#Priority#Status
1#Play Piano#Personal#2#true#
2#Excersice 2.1 - Maths#Personal#5#false#
3#Play Games with Friends#Other#1#true#
```

Unfortunately when I import the text file into the JTable, it only displays the Index, Task, Type and Priority columns. Please can someone explain why is this the case and how do I correct this error. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code for exporting data:

```
private void btnExportActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("TaskInfo.txt");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);

        for(int row = 0; row < tblTaskInfo.getRowCount(); row++) {     
            String headers = String.valueOf(tblTaskInfo.getColumnName(row));
            pw.print(headers);
            pw.print("#");
        }   

        pw.println("");
        for(int row = 0; row < model.getRowCount(); ++row) {
            for(int column = 0; column <model.getColumnCount(); ++column)
            {
               String s = model.getValueAt(row,column).toString();
               pw.print(s);
               pw.print("#");
            }
            pw.println("");
        }      
        pw.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File Saved");
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Failure");
    }
}
```

Here is my code for importing data:

```
private void btnImportActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    
        try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("TaskInfo.txt");   
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        // get the first line
        // get the columns name from the first line
        // set columns name to the jtable model
        String firstLine = br.readLine().trim();
        String[] columnsName = firstLine.split("#");
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)tblTaskInfo.getModel();
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnsName);
        
        // get lines from txt file
        Object[] tableLines = br.lines().toArray();
        
        // extratct data from lines
        // set data to jtable model
        for(int i = 0; i < tableLines.length; i++)
        {
        String line = tableLines[i].toString().trim();
        String[] dataRow = line.split("#");
        model.addRow(dataRow);
        }
        
        
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Task.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}
```

Comment: You should stop deleting your posts when you got an answer or when you found your issue. (As you did with your previous post ~ 2 hours go) Because that information might still be helpful for somebody in the future.

Comment: What debugging have you done? Did you verify the "columnNames" array contains 5 values? The basic code looks reasonable. Post a proper [mre] if you need more help. Also don't use code like `Object[] tableLines = br.lines().toArray();`. It may work fine for a small file but it loads the entire file into memory. You need a loop to process each line anyway, so just read one line of data in the loop to minimize the memory needed by your class.

Comment: I have not debugged nor verified anything. The only thing that I have verified is wether the text file is available. Thanks for sharing the "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" but do you perhaps have any other tips to minimise my code. Additionally, thanks for suggesting that I need to use a for loop. I will try to implement these ideas into my new code.

Comment: Thanks camickr. I will try and implement this into my new code.

Comment: *I have not debugged nor verified anything* - then why did you ask the question? The first step is to verify your logic to see what the actual data is. Never assume the data is correct. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43197145/131872 for a working [mre] showing how to read data from a text file into a JTable.

Comment: Sorry. Let me rephrase myself. I have verified that when importing my data, it displays everything except for the Status column (perhaps because it is a boolean variable). I have not written code to display an error message to verify if the code is working correctly.

Comment: You stated: *it only displays the Index, Task, Type and Priority columns.*  Now you just added: *(perhaps because it is a boolean variable).* - Are you now stating you get 5 column headers but only data in the first 4 are displayed? If so then yes, the problem is because you can't load String data into the model and expect it to be treated as a Boolean value. You need to convert the data before adding it. So you would copy the String data to an Array of Object data and then convert the last column.

Comment: Yes I am stating that I have 5 column headers until I import the data which results in 4 headers being displayed. Thanks

Comment: Well, the boolean data has nothing to do with the column headers being displayed. You still haven't answered my first two questions. Good luck, there is nothing else we can help with.