# Read file.txt and split (:)

Tags: java, file

I have file txt with format like this

```
Nama: John
Biologi: 8
Kimia: 9
Fisika: 10

Nama: Peter
Biologi: 10
Kimia: 8
Fisika: 7

Nama: Steve
Biologi: 8
Kimia: 9
Fisika: 6
```

> I try to read it with buffer reader but it wont show anything when i print out, i want to get the value and store it into arraylist of string
> here is my try.....

```
try{
        File database = new File(file);
        FileReader fileInput = new FileReader(database);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(fileInput);
        String line = in.readLine();
        String[] data;
        while (line != null){
            data = line.split(":");
            list_Siswa.add(data);
            line = in.readLine();
        }
       String datas = "";
       for (String[] dataSiswa : list_Siswa){//for each to print data into variable
           datas += "\nNama: " + dataSiswa[0] + "\n" +
                   "Kimia: " + dataSiswa[1] + "\n" +
                   "Biologi: " + dataSiswa[2] + "\n" +
                   "Fisika: " + dataSiswa[3] + "\n";
       }
       System.out.println(datas);
        in.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
   }
```

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2 (That is the error i get)
>
> i'm trying the excat format to be print out as the file

Comment: *but it wont show anything when i print out* - I don't see where you print the data? Add debug code to your while loop to display each line of data that you read. Problem solving is a step by step approach. You need to isolate where the problem is and then fix it. You can't just say it doesn't work. Also your code is adding the Array that contains the data. Is that really what you want?

Comment: yes i want to add Array that contains the data.

Comment: i'm trying the excat format to be print out as the file

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'toList' in 'Stream'

Comment: still the error (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2)

Comment: Your file contains rows, each containing two pairs of values separated by `:`. if you split each row, you will only get arrays of length 2.

Comment: can i ask more question?, how to store the result into String?

Comment: (1-) Well its been over 2 hours and you still haven't answered the simple question, did you add a display inside your loop to verify you are actually reading data from the file. If you read data, then there should be no problem with your code. Without a proper [mre] there is nothing we can do to help.

Comment: yes i add display, it getting hards because the result is not the same when i store it into String variable

Comment: And the result was??? I have no idea what "it" refers to. I have no idea what you expect to see in your String variable or what you currently see in your String variable. As stated above you have also had over 2 hours to post your [mre] demonstrating the problem. Since you haven't we can't help. Here is an example of an MRE. It demonstrates how to simulate reading data from a file. You should be able to modify it for your data and then add your processing to create your List with whatever data you want.

Comment: Sorry bout that, maybe i should try again, but please dont get mad at me and give (-1), i've just try to learn, moreover since english is not my national language, i encounter some problem in showing what i want to do with my code, thnkyou for the respon, i will keep try n learn from my mistake... sorry bout that..., feel bad to get you angry

Comment: Oops, forgot to include the link to the MRE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43197056/fill-jtable-with-local-json-file/43197145#43197145

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add each line to the variable `list_Siswa`. So for instance the first element of `list_Siswa` will be `["Nama"," John"]`, and so `data_Siswa[0]` equals `"Nama"` and `data_Siswa[1]` equals `" John"`. Then `data_Siswa[2]` throws an error, because there is no such element in the array.

The code isn't smart enough to see `Nama: John` and assume the following lines are grades that should be associated with John. If you want that, you'll have to do it yourself.

Comment: i think you really understand what i want from my code