# Storing LinkedList values from a file and showing it to JFrame

Tags: java, file, swing, linked-list, file-handling

I have a question to ask. To cut this short, I have a problem regarding writing the elements to a file and then load it to the JFrame me and my classmates are working with. The simple draft of the program is good so far, and the writing of the contents to the file by just using a user-defined function is also great. But I want to try using LinkedList to write the contents using the elements I provided (Because we also need to delete the contents one by one).

In the draft I tried using a 2-dim LinkedList to make sure that each of my index have 3 elements inside, namely "name", "phone", and "email". Also to organize the data in their respective order, I used JTable, when I used it without LinkedList, it's ok, but as I used the LinkedList, it throws an error. Also the thrown error is called "IndexOutofBoundsException", I think the error is in the method called "loadFileContents", but idk how to fix it.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class FileContentApp {
    private static final String FILE_PATH = "contacts.txt";
    private static DefaultTableModel tableModel;
    public static LinkedList<LinkedList<String>> fileContacts = new LinkedList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Contact File");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        topPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("Contacts");
        titleLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        topPanel.add(titleLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JButton addButton = new JButton("+");
        addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                showDialog(frame);
            }
        });
        JButton settingButton = new JButton("...");
        buttonPanel.add(addButton);
        buttonPanel.add(settingButton);
        topPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.getContentPane().add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        contentPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        JTable table = createTable();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        contentPanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        loadFileContents();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static JTable createTable() {
        tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
        tableModel.addColumn("Name");
        tableModel.addColumn("Phone");
        tableModel.addColumn("Email");
        JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
        table.setGridColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        table.setShowGrid(true);
        return table;
    }

    private static void showDialog(JFrame parentFrame) {
    LinkedList<String> listContact = new LinkedList<>();
    JDialog dialog = new JDialog(parentFrame, "Add Contact", true);
    dialog.setSize(300, 200);
    dialog.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(parentFrame);

    JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 2));
    inputPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
    JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name : ");
    JTextField nameField = new JTextField();
    JLabel phoneLabel = new JLabel("Phone : ");
    JTextField phoneField = new JTextField();
    JLabel emailLabel = new JLabel("Email : ");
    JTextField emailField = new JTextField();

    inputPanel.add(nameLabel);
    inputPanel.add(nameField);
    inputPanel.add(phoneLabel);
    inputPanel.add(phoneField);
    inputPanel.add(emailLabel);
    inputPanel.add(emailField);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
    JButton addButton = new JButton("Add");
    addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String name = nameField.getText();
            String phone = phoneField.getText();
            String email = emailField.getText();
            listContact.add(name);
            listContact.add(phone);
            listContact.add(email);
            fileContacts.add(listContact);
            addContactToFile(fileContacts);
            loadFileContents();
            dialog.dispose();
        }
    });
    buttonPanel.add(addButton);

    dialog.add(inputPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    dialog.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    dialog.setVisible(true);
}


    private static void addContactToFile(LinkedList<LinkedList<String>> fileContacts) {
        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(FILE_PATH, true))) {
            writer.write(fileContacts.get(0) + "\n" + fileContacts.get(1) + "\n" + fileContacts.get(2));
            writer.newLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void loadFileContents() {
    tableModel.setRowCount(0); // Clear existing table data

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILE_PATH))) {
        String line;
        int lineCount = 0;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (lineCount % 3 == 0) {
                fileContacts.add(new LinkedList<>());
            }
            fileContacts.get(lineCount / 3).add(line);
            lineCount++;
        }

        for (LinkedList<String> contact : fileContacts) {
            tableModel.addRow(contact.toArray());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Here is the whole code I used, I'm still inexperienced in regards of using this part of Java so it's kind of clunky, and used some ChatGPT.

Comment: Using a LinkedList is the wrong approach. Related data should be stored together, not as a separate item in the List. The data can be read from the file and added directly to the TableModel. When you want to save the data you get the data from the TableModel and write it to a file. I would suggest that the file should contain one row of data for each "Contact". So maybe the name, phone, email is separated by a special character, like a ",". Then you read a row of data, parse it and then add the row to the table model. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43197145/131872 for the most basic example.

Comment: A more advanced design would be to create a custom "Contact" object and a custom "ContactTableModel" for your data. Then when you read the data from the file you would create a Contact object and add it to the ContactTableModel. See the example at the start of [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) to get you started.